# How can I enable the QueryFilters again in EntityFramework Core after calling IgnoreQueryFilters?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is what I have, one `Application` instance that contains two `Tags`, one marked as `IsDeleted` and one not. My `Application` and `Tag` class all have an `IsDeleted` property on the model.

```
public class Application 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}
```

My `ApplicationConfiguration` looks like this

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Application> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Application");
        builder.HasQueryFilter(d => !d.IsDeleted);

        builder.HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.Property(d => d.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasQueryFilter(d => !d.IsDeleted);
     }
}
```

As you can see the query filter is applied on `IsDeleted`. For `Document` and `Tag`, I have the same query filter applied

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(d => !d.IsDeleted);
```

In my repository, I have this a `GetAll` method that looks like this

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] include, bool includeAllRecords = false)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = includeAllRecords ? Context.Set<TEntity>().IgnoreQueryFilters() : Context.Set<TEntity>();

    if (include != null)
    {
        query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, includePath) => current.Include(includePath));
    }

    return query;
}
```

See the `IgnoreQueryFilters` when I pass the Boolean parameter. Now I can make queries over the `ApplicationRepository`:

```
var appsWithJustActiveTags = ApplicationRepository.GetAll(new[] { "Tags" }).ToList();
var allTags = ApplicationRepository.GetAll(new[] { "Tags" }, true).ToList();
```

Both queries return the correct values for the tags when I pass the Boolean parameter, on the first one I get the Application with the Tags that are not deleted and in the second one I get the same application with all the tags including the deleted one. However, if I change the order of the execution of this queries, then both return the same result

```
var allTags = ApplicationRepository.GetAll(new[] { "Tags" }, true).ToList();
var appsWithJustActiveTags = ApplicationRepository.GetAll(new[] { "Tags" }).ToList();
```

Seems that EntityFramework Core disables the QueryFilters for all queries in the same Context if you call `Context.Set<TEntity>().IgnoreQueryFilters();` and any subsequent calls to a simple `Context.Set<TEntity>();` don't get the filters back again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May you can use Non-Tracking Query for this type progress.

Her is the link for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

A simple usage, may you have to add a few things. I did not debug this code.

**GetAllWithoutFilter**

Context.Set<**TEntity**>().***AsNoTracking***().IgnoreQueryFilters();

**GetAllAsNoTracking**

Context.Set<**TEntity**>();

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllWithoutFilter(string[] include)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().IgnoreQueryFilters();

    if (include != null)
    {
        query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, includePath) => current.Include(includePath));
    }

    return query;
}


public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] include)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query =  Context.Set<TEntity>();

    if (include != null)
    {
        query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, includePath) => current.Include(includePath));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. I want to persist the data in case I need it, but I will try to run it on this way and see coming back with final results

Comment: @Zinov The answerer is right, if you use tracking queries, they affect each other. Even in your first scenario, after executing to second query, the `appsWithJustActiveTags` list elements will be no more *with just active tags*, but *with all tags*.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you join the discussion room that I created here? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165293/queryfilters-in-entityframework